# How to stop lavaan from autogenerating covariances? (Package: lavaan)

Tags: r-lavaan

I'm having trouble getting rid of autogenerated covariances when I fit a SEM model using sem() and lavaan() (package lavaan).

#Specifying the model using lavaan package

```
spec.mod <- "
TC ~ Ele + dist + pet + MD + Dnt
pet ~ Ele + ppt
MD ~ Dnt + Ft + dist + ppt
Dnt ~ Ft + Ele + dist + ppt
Ft ~ Ele
"
```

#Fitting an sem model

## With lavaan function

```
kk <- lavaan(spec.mod, data = trans1, auto.var = TRUE)
```

## With Sem function

fitmod <- sem(spec.mod, data = trans1)

## Model summary with lavaan

```
summary(kk, fit.measures = TRUE, rsquare = TRUE)
```

## I have commanded auto.var = TRUE, but I couldn’t find any increase in the df and are same in both the cases.

I am supposed to get the df=12
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9FgVz.jpg)

## Model summary with sem

```
summary(fitmod, fit.measures = TRUE, rsquare = TRUE)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qeDAk.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

`auto.var=` is about estimating variances.  Covariances among exogenous factors are controlled by `auto.cov.lv.x=`.  See the `?lavOptions` help page for descriptions.